# Entity Framework: Generate Database From Model removes Stored Procedures from Model Store

Tags: entity-framework

I am using a stored procedure with an EF 4 model.

To accomplish this I'm going through the following steps:

1. I add the stored procedure to my Model Store by Updating from the database and selecting it.
2. Added a function import to point to the stored procedure
3. The stored procedure returns the result of a query joining multiple tables etc so in the "*Returns Collection Of*" area I specify a *Complex Type* and use the *Get Column Information* button below to generate the complex type returned.

Here is where my issue arises: **when I use the "Generate Database From Model" option, it removes the stored procedure mapping from the Model Store.**

My question is:

**How can I use the "Generate Database From Model" option but ignore the Stored Procedures mapping?**

In the model properties there is a "Database Generation Workflow" that is TablePerTypeStrategy but apparently this has the added effect of removing stored procedures from the model store.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These two approaches should not be used together! Use either database first (Update model from database) or model first (Generate database from model). I'm even surprised that it didn't delete your stored procedures in the database as well.

When you select Generate database from model it deletes whole storage description and mapping from your EDMX and generates a new one.

Comment: How do you propose generating Stored Procedures using a Model First approach?

Comment: @CodeGrue: I do not propose creating stored procedures in model first approach. Model first is for scenarios where database is dump and doesn't contain any logic = no views, no stored procedures, no triggers, no sql functions, etc. It is possible to create those objects but you must hardcode them to SQL generation template - that is pretty ugly hack.

Comment: Why are you surprised that Generate Database didn't delete SPs from the database? It doesn't touch any database, it generates a .sql file for you. Even then, the sql in the file does not contain anything that would drop a stored procedure.

Comment: I highly disagree. Model First "generate database from model" should support everything defined in the edmx file including views which it also turns into tables instead of preserving as views. It should totally round trip database->model->database in regards to the features it does support even if not all features are supported.

Answer (score 2):

I am using model first but also mapping stored procedures to function imports. Unfortunately when I make updates to the model and try to generate the database from the model, it removes my stored procedures and unmaps my function imports.

To get around this, I do an undo after I generate the database from the model on the EDMX (and keep the updated sql script). This updates the database just fine for me and restores my stored procedures and function imports as well.

Comment: I tried adding a new association and doing this, but after undoing EF claimed it didn't have a proper mapping for the association... so I'm not sure this always works.